# Beautify excessively long conditionals

Tags: ruby

I have a line of code that looks something like:

`if a && b && c && d && e && f`

Is there a recommended way to clean this up? Perhaps some way to move it to multiple lines?

Comment: The answers you get on this question will probably only help you improve your code cosmetically. If you have that many joined conditions, there are probably more serious structural problems with your program. [Give this a read](http://www.confidentruby.com/)

Comment: If you have so many parameters and conditions, I would consider a state machine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can write it as multiple lines, and that is pretty common when you have a large number of conditions.

```
if a && b &&
   c && d &&
   e && f
  do_something
else
  "Well, with all those conditions, it wasn't likely anyway, was it?"
end
```

(Personally, I tend to combine long grouped conditions into variables so that the condition in the if-expression is short and it's easy to follow the logic. You can use the same multi-line syntax with that.)

Comment: +1 for descriptive variables (also short methods OK too)

Answer (score 1):

If this is in a method definition and there is nothing more to do if the condition is not satisfied, then

```
return unless a
return unless b
return unless c
return unless d
return unless e
return unless f
... # Do something
```

Otherwise

```
...
tap do
  break unless a
  break unless b
  break unless c
  break unless d
  break unless e
  break unless f
  ... # Do something
end
...
```

Comment: I don't care much for this approach because it includes repetition, even if it is just the 'return/break unless' statements.

Answer (score -1):

Since it's all about readability versus speed i updated this answer, if speed is an issue add the if Condition.true? at the end of the line. The benefit of this approach is that you don't have a limit on the number of conditions that need to be checked.

```
class Condition
    @@is = true
    def self.true?
        @@is
    end
    def self.add condition
        @@is = @@is && condition
    end
end

x = 0
Condition.add "a very long string equals" == "a very long string equals" if Condition.true?
puts Condition.true?
Condition.add "a very long string equals" == "another long string" if Condition.true?
puts Condition.true?
Condition.add "a very long string equals" == "another veeeeeeeeeeeeery long string" if Condition.true?
puts Condition.true?
Condition.add x = 1 if Condition.true?

puts Condition.true?
puts x
```

gives

```
true
false
false
false
0
```

Comment: Hmm, this seems pretty messy to me (I'm not the downvoter). Anyway, it occurs to me that the use of array means that everything gets evaluated every time anyway so you might as well be using `all?`.

Comment: with all, after the evaluation, all comparisons are made, not with my solution

Comment: The comparison isn't the issue, the evaluation is. Consider this condition: `false && User.find(:all)`. The `User.find(:all)` never needs to get called (and doesn't with a regular short circuit) but it does with your solution. Up front when you stuff it into the array.

Comment: that is correct so i would only use this solution in cases where you have long conditions that are otherwise difficult to read and where readability is more important than speed of execution or the evaluation of the conditions doesn't take much time

Comment: @pguardiario i update the answer with a less messy approach i hope and without evaluation if you don't want that